# usesGroupingSeparator не дает получить правильное число

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Помогите решить проблему. У меня есть textfield в который вводятся целые числа. По желанию клиента числа должны группироваться. Т.е. выглядеть не 51141, а 51 141. Я использую для этого NSNumberFormatter, ну и соответственно usesGroupingSeparator. Так вот дальше мне для расчетов нужно  получить это число из textfield. Я делаю это так

```
double costOnePack440Int = [_priceGert440TextField.text integerValue];
```

Но возникает проблема. Мне приходит не полное мое число 51141, а только цифры до GroupingSeparator, т.е. я получаю только 51! Как решить эту проблему? Чтобы и сепаратор использовать и получить мое число целиком?

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается проблема решалась легко и просто. Вот так:

```
double costOnePack440Int = [[_priceGert440TextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] integerValue];
```